# Программно запустить и остановить exe файл

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте!
Например есть программка с названием: prog_1.1.exe

```
nt APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
_In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    if ( CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, _T("prog_1.1.exe")) )//то есть уже запущено
        if ( GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS )
        {
            //действия если запущена
        }
while(true);
}
```

Как сделать так, что если я запускаю второй экземпляр этого файла то он должен прекратить выполнение первого экземпляра?

И второй вопрос как запустить ее на компьютере подключенным в сеть если есть общая папка?

Не могли бы Вы привести пример? кода...

Comment: первый способ - убить процесс, но imho лучше просигнализировать первому экзепляру о том что ему нужно завершаться, для этого заменить mutex на event, сначала пытаться открывать его, если получилось, то затем установить его, первый процес в свою очередь дождавшись установки event'а, корректно завершается.

Comment: для запуска программы на другом компьютере можно воспользоваться PsExec из PsTools

Comment: Здравствуйте уважаемый автор! Скажите пожалуйста, выше приведенные примеры (коды) на каком среде выполняются?